# Semi-Align Characters Vertically

Tags: html, css

Complete noob here,

I am trying to semi align a stacked clock with the hours on top and the minutes below, the issue is is that at certain times the alignment of the numbers looks very off which is shown below, if I fully align the numbers vertically I feel thaty the spacing between the numbers horizontally will be either too large or small, is there a way to have a compromise between the two?. Sometimes the clock looks great but sometimes it looks a bit off.

I am trying to replicate the AOD clock introduced with Android 12,

Here are the files

https://github.com/Crucial-hash/material-you-clock

You cant screenshot the always on display so I have tried my best by taking a photo side by side.

Clock Image

[image: 1]

```js
function displayTime(){
    var dateTime = new Date();
    var hrs = dateTime.getHours();
    var min = dateTime.getMinutes();

    if (hrs > 12){
        hrs = hrs -12
    }
    
    if (hrs > 12){
        hrs = hrs -12
    }

    if (hrs < 10){
        hrs = "0" + hrs
    }

    if (min < 10){
        min = "0" + min
    }

    document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = hrs;
    document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = min;
}

setInterval(displayTime, 10);
var width = screen.width;
var height = screen.height;
```

```css
@font-face{
    font-family: myfont;
    src:url(productsans.ttf);
}

body{
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    background-color: black;
}

span{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 449px;
    width: 449px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.container{
    font-family: 'myfont';
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 36%;
    left: 28%;
    transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
    font-size: 370px;
}

.container1{
    font-family: 'myfont';
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 64%;
    left: 28%;
    transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
    font-size: 370px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Android 12 Digital Clock</title>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
         <span id="hours"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="container1">
        <span id="minutes"></span>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Also check your question as I cannot see the example you say is “shown below”.

Answer (score 0):

To center your containers, just remove position absolute and use flex property.
Using flexbox you don't need to use 2 differents class to center elements.

```js
function displayTime(){
    var dateTime = new Date();
    var hrs = dateTime.getHours();
    var min = dateTime.getMinutes();

    if (hrs > 12){
        hrs = hrs -12
    }
    
    if (hrs > 12){
        hrs = hrs -12
    }

    if (hrs < 10){
        hrs = "0" + hrs
    }

    if (min < 10){
        min = "0" + min
    }

    document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = hrs;
    document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = min;
}

setInterval(displayTime, 10);
var width = screen.width;
var height = screen.height;
```

```css
@font-face{
    font-family: myfont;
    src:url(productsans.ttf);
}

body{
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    background-color: black;
}

span{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 449px;
    width: 449px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.container{
    font-family: 'myfont';
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /*position: absolute; REMOVE
    top: 36%;
    left: 28%;
    transform: translate(-100%, -50%);*/
    font-size: 370px;
}

 /*.container1{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'myfont';
    color: #fff;
   position: absolute; REMOVE
    top: 64%;
    left: 28%;
    transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
    font-size: 370px;
}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Android 12 Digital Clock</title>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
         <span id="hours"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <span id="minutes"></span>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```